# Is this phrasing correct?

Tags: terminology

Suppose a survey asks "In general, what do you think of your time - would you say you always feel rushed, only sometimes feel rushed, or almost never feel rushed?" to a nationally representative sample of American adults.

The results are that 20% of the males answered always, 41% of the males answered sometimes, and 39% of the males answered almost never.

Assuming that it is legitimate to generalize the results of the sample to the population, is it is correct to say that *most men sometimes feel rushed?*

- One argument for why the statement is valid is because *sometimes*
  was the most popular response among the males - most males chose *sometimes*.
- However, an argument for why the statement is invalid is because the percentage of men who answered *sometimes* was less than 50%, so the word "most" cannot be used in this context.

So, which of the above reasonings is correct?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "most" would imply that a majority (i.e., >50%) of men answered "sometimes".

You could say that a "plurality" of men responded  that they "sometimes feel rushed". E.g., "when asked ... , a plurality (41%) of men responded that they 'sometimes' feel rushed". Or alternatively just say that the most popular response was "x", or something along those lines.

Comment: So the statement "most men sometimes feel rushed" is false in this case, because less than 50% of men answered "sometimes"?

Comment: Yes, in this context, the majority of people would read "most" and assume that that meant >50%.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small wrinkle you should consider: the difference between 41% and 39% may well be non-significant (i.e. within the range of sampling error). In this case, the statement recommended by @FelixSingletonThorn might mislead your audience about the population despite being technically true about your sample.

I think it would be more accurate and robust to state that **most men feel rushed *at least sometimes***, or **the majority of men feel rushed *at least sometimes***.

Answer (score 1):

In your phrasing you need to be very clear what you want to state. For example, if a person is always rushed then necessarily it is sometimes rushed. So most men feel sometimes rushed, if you want to make explicit that they don't always feel rushes then explain it.